# Is there a method to limit/clamp a number?

Tags: ruby, clamp

I wrote the following code, which keeps `x` within the range `(a..b)`. In pseudo code:

```
(if x < a, x = a; if x > b, x = b)
```

In Ruby it would be something like:

```
x = [a, [x, b].min].max
```

As it is quite basic and useful function, I was wondering if there is a native method to do that in ruby.

As of Ruby 2.3.3 there is apparently no method like this, what would be the shortest/more readable way to do it?

I found:

```
x = [a, x, b].sort[1]
```

so far, but I'm not sure if it is more readable.

Comment: Just a matter of interest, from for exactly native function?

Comment: You've answered your own question there - nice use of the sort function. I don't think you'll get much more readable than that.

Comment: you problably mean: `x2 = [a, [x, b].min].max`. It looks ok to me, use basic generic methods to build the rest.

Comment: Interesting use of sort.. makes the whole thing independant of the order..

Comment: @tokland: you are right. I edited it

Comment: I love your cryptic version. You should put it in as an answer so I can up vote it.

Comment: @drewish Thanks. I found it somewhere (in the R communauty if I remember well). A create an answer

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Ruby 2.4.0 introduces [`Comparable#clamp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp):

```
523.clamp(0, 100)        #=> 100
```

Comment: The best part: the reason ruby has no clamp method is they can't stop arguing about what to name the function.

Comment: This has finally been added now.

Comment: Haha, I implemented Comparable#clamp. Took them long enough to merge my patch... ;-)

Answer (score 37):

My own answer : NO

However

```
x = [a, x, b].sort[1]
```

Is a solution.

Comment: Not gonna lie, that's sexy.

Comment: I think this might be the single prettiest line of code I've ever seen.

Comment: The cool thing is that the order in which you put the min, max and x does not even matter.

Answer (score 12):

I did this:

```
class Numeric
  def clamp min, max
    [[self, max].min, min].max
  end
end
```

So whenever I want to clamp anything, I can just call:

```
x.clamp(min, max)
```

Which I find pretty readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which borrows heavily from the actual implementation:

```
unless Comparable.method_defined? :clamp
  module Comparable
    def clamp min, max
      if max-min<0
        raise ArgumentError, 'min argument must be smaller than max argument'
      end
      self>max ? max : self<min ? min : self
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The most appealing solution for now in my opinion is the sort option:

```
[min,x,max].sort[1]
```

When you don't mind monkey patching existing core classes.
I think the range class is a good candidate for a clamp method

```
class Range
  def clamp(v)
    [min,v,max].sort[1]
  end
end

(min..max).clamp(v)
```

Or the plain array object. I don't like this, because the clamp function only is correct for 3 element arrays

```
class Array
    def clamp
      sort[1]
    end
end
```

You can call it like this:

```
[a,x,b].clamp
```

Comment: Calling clamp over an array or a range seems to be really deceiving. That is not a result someone would think about. Monkey patching numeric or comparable looks like something easier to understand IMHO.