# How to return a value in a specified range in better way with ruby

Tags: ruby

I add a method to `Numeric` class like this:

```
class Numeric
  def limitate(min, max)
    return self if self.between?(min,max)
    return max if self > max
    min
  end
end
```

I want to get a value if the value is in a specified range, and if it is outside range it should return maximum or minimum value.

Can I write it more simply? And how?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020787/is-there-a-limit-clamp-function-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is sadly [no clamp in Ruby](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4574) yet I think. Another way to write it is:

```
v = [[v, min].max, max].min
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make sure that min is lower than max first.
Otherwise your method will semanticly error if the user forgot which one should go first, `min` or `max`.

```
min, max = max, min if min > max
```